# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_{n^{\alpha}}^{n^{\alpha+1}}\log^2\left(1+\sin1/x\right)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Study the convergence of the following series as $\alpha>0$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_{n^{\alpha}}^{n^{\alpha+1}}\log^2\left(1+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$$

This is the first time I do an exercise with a series defined by a integral and I hold it is equal to study the convergence of the improper integral (isn't it?):

$$\lim_{N \to +\infty}\int_{1^{\alpha}}^{N^{\alpha+1}}\log^2\left(1+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$$

or, do I need to follow a different path?

Comment: You are incorrect about the second expression being equivalent to the first, i.e., there can be overlaps in the ranges covered by each term.

Comment: At least for small $\alpha$, the intervals of integration in the sum will always significantly overlap, e.g., for $\alpha = 1$ you get $[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], \ldots$, so the sum will always be much larger than your integral and may exhibit different convergence behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for small $\epsilon$, $$\log^2 (1+\epsilon) \approx \epsilon^2$$ and $$\sin \epsilon \approx \epsilon$$ so for large $x$, $$\log^2 \left( 1 + \sin \frac{1}{x} \right) \approx \frac{1}{x^2}.$$ Therefore, $$\int_{n^\alpha}^{n^{\alpha+1}} \log^2 \left( 1 + \sin \frac{1}{x} \right)\, dx \approx \int_{n^\alpha}^{n^{\alpha+1}} \frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{n^\alpha} - \frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}.$$
Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ converges iff $\alpha > 1$, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}$ always converges, so we have convergence iff $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: Definitely it is much less horrific than it is appears